# Solr error 404 File not found. Problem with indexing website

Tags: html, solr

I'm new in Solr and I have to index my website (it's an example created with flask and it's an html file) with Solr.
I create a new core:

```
sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c mycollection -n data_driven_schema_configs"
```

Then:

```
bin/post -c mycollection -filetypes html http://"mywebsite...."
```

but I have this error:

```
    SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/update/extract?commit=true
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/mycollection/update/extract</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>404</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Not Found</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I read solr documentation that says:

> If you are not working with an example configset, the jars required to use Solr Cell will not be loaded automatically. You will need to configure your solrconfig.xml to find the ExtractingRequestHandler and its dependencies:

```
    <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
```

but I don't understand where I can put this code. Maybe, I put in solrconfig.xml? and where?
Then:

> You can then configure the ExtractingRequestHandler in solrconfig.xml. The following is the default configuration found in Solr’s _default configset, which you can modify as needed:

```
<

requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                startup="lazy"
                class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="lowernames">true</str>
    <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I think that has to be added in solrconfig.xml, has it?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Yes, it should go in solrconfig.xml - make sure you add the tags correctly. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I do. It didn’t’t work

Comment: When you're staring up Solr, it will show which libraries are being loaded (and from where) in the log. Does the solr-cell libraries you've added show up? What does the startup log show about the requesthandler you've added? (and you _did_ add the lib instructions as well?)

Comment: I can post you confiset, or can you be more explicit? I'm new in solr and I don't understand